# Full Screen Mobile Menu and Scroll limit to its contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good morning,

I made a Mobile menu that is activated by clicking on a button on the main page.

This one takes the whole page. On the other hand, I have to limit the scroll so that I don't see the whole page. I need to be able to scroll the content of the menu, so the fixed position doesn't help.
How can I force the viewport to the content of my `div` when it is in `display: block`?

The first solution I tried is [Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt9w6o5f/1/)

**But I don't want the menu to have infinite scroll, only on its content**

The second that I've tried is [Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt9w6o5f/3/)

Thank you in advance, I've tried various solutions, but nothing works yet.

Comment: Please show us your various solution and your code

Comment: can u plz share ur code in codepen?

Comment: One of the solution is https://jsfiddle.net/Lt9w6o5f/1/ but i don't want the menu infinite scroll, only on it content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are on right track its not the scroll which menu have its you body
>   element scroll please see below example, i just make some borders to
>   clear you

If you see inner scroll is menu scroll while the outer one is your body scroll as menu is is inside body that why its visible

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("over");
    $(".menu").addClass("active");
  });
```

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
.over{
 overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    /* width: auto; */
    /* height: 100%; */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    
display:none;
}
.menu.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button>Toggle menu</button>
<div class="menu">
  Menu

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your help, is it possible to unactive scroll on body when the menu is open ?

Comment: Yes as you example is incomplete for that you need to call a function on menu click by which just add class to body with overflow hidden properties

Comment: Update the question with generic idea you can customize

Comment: Excellent, thanks for you answer, it help me well.
 i'm now trying to make the div scroll, it only work at height : 500px in position absolute ^^

Comment: Good to hear that, Are you talking about menu scroll? but default its height is 100% if content exceed then 100% scroll will come automatically

Comment: Yes, i set now height to 100% and it fix it ! Thank for you support :) help me so much

Comment: Yes you can try that but actually i didnt get your point, Can you please update you latest code in question or in comment section

Comment: when i scroll the home-page, and click on the button, my div is display but a part of content come over it.
the solution i found didn't solve the problem because it display the home page scrollbar instead of back to top then hidden the overflow

Comment: ok got it set its `z-index:1000;` like `.menu{z-index:1000;}`

Comment: Thanks, my error is to set it as absolute instead of fixed :)

Comment: @Max Good to hear that you solved it by yourself! Cheers